# Как работать с TUN на с++

Tags: c++, linux

Как работать с tun на с++ и обрабатывать пакеты
+Можете ли скинуть какой-нить материал по TUN

Comment: Прочитать документацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В двух словах:

1. Подключить заголовочные файлы `<linux/if.h>` и `<linux/if_tun.h>`
2. Создать и настроить виртуальный интерфейс средствами из этих файлов (также могут пригодиться обычные средства вроде ioctl интерфейсов и маршрутизации - настроить адрес, прописать маршрут)
3. Получить файловый дескриптор виртуального интерфейса и работать с ним так, как если бы это был обычный файл или сокет. Только в этом случае это будет сетевой интерфейс

   - Запись в fd приведет к получению сетевым стеком ядра пакета **из вашего интерфейса**
   - Чтение из fd возможно при отправке сетевым стеком ядра пакета **в ваш интерфейс**
   - Можно использовать select и прочие **инструменты для работы с fd**

Как обычно в Linux - гибко, универсально и надо разбираться, "курить мануалы" так сказать

Посмотрите примеры: https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/

По поводу обработки пакетов - это крайне обширная тема, могу лишь сказать, что заголовки большинства распространенных протоколов (ethernet, ip, tcp, udp, icmp) уже есть в виде готовых структур в заголовочных файлах netinet/*.h, и лучше использовать их, а не писать самому

Не забывайте, что в сетевой интерфейс пакеты уходят и приходят оттуда в RAW-виде, то есть начиная с уровня Ethernet